# Need numeric argument for chmod system call to change only the sticky bit

Tags: linux, file-permissions, system-calls, chmod

I know pretty much how to use `chmod` directly from the command line. But I'm not quite sure if we can mimic its

```
chmod o+t filename
```

function. I usually call it directly with:

```
chmod(filename, 0666)
```

But instead of setting the permissions, I want to know how to add a permission without affecting the other ones, like `chmod o+t filename`. Something like `chmod(filename, 1777)` will also set the sticky bit, but it also sets all the other bits. What number should we pass to `chmod` to let it only change the sticky bit? thanks in advance.

Comment: Retrieve the current mode bits, modify them to set the sticky bit, issue chmod() to write the new value back to the filesystem.

Comment: As @keshlam mentioned, you should get the current permission using stat(). You can then bitwise OR the sticky bit to the existing permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, first read current mode bits with stat(), then do chmod().

The thing to take home with you is that you shouldn't be working with numeric values directly but instead trust those defined in header files. See `man 2 chmod` for what is available.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct stat st;

  if(argc < 1) return 2;

  if(stat(argv[1], &st) != 0) {
    perror(argv[1]);
    return 2;
  }

  printf("mode before chmod() = %o\n", st.st_mode);

  if(chmod(argv[1], st.st_mode | S_ISVTX) != 0) {
    perror(argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  if(stat(argv[1], &st) != 0) {
    perror(argv[1]);
    return 2;
  }

  printf("mode after chmod() = %o\n", st.st_mode);

  return 0;
}
```

Have fun with homework!

Comment: Thanks a lot. And how do I use this mechanism to unset it then?

Comment: This has a pretty glaring race condition - what if another process calls `chmod()` on the file between your call to `stat()` and your call to `chmod()`? Is there an atomic solution?